# Problem in running the environment.yml file

Tags: dependencies, install.packages, cloning, 3d-reconstruction, 3d-modelling

I cloned a repository from github and the environment.yml is not working properly. the dependencies that is present in the file are
dependencies:

- _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
- _openmp_mutex=5.1=1_gnu
- blas=1.0=mkl
- brotlipy=0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003
- bzip2=1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
- ca-certificates=2022.10.11=h06a4308_0
- certifi=2022.9.24=py39h06a4308_0
- cffi=1.15.1=py39h5eee18b_2
- cuda=11.6.2=0
- cuda-cccl=11.6.55=hf6102b2_0
- cuda-command-line-tools=11.6.2=0
- cuda-compiler=11.6.2=0
- cuda-cudart=11.6.55=he381448_0
- cuda-cudart-dev=11.6.55=h42ad0f4_0
- cuda-cuobjdump=11.6.124=h2eeebcb_0
- cuda-cupti=11.6.124=h86345e5_0
- cuda-cuxxfilt=11.6.124=hecbf4f6_0
- cuda-driver-dev=11.6.55=0
- cuda-gdb=11.8.86=0
- cuda-libraries=11.6.2=0
- cuda-libraries-dev=11.6.2=0
- cuda-memcheck=11.8.86=0
- cuda-nsight=11.8.86=0
- cuda-nsight-compute=11.8.0=0
- cuda-nvcc=11.6.124=hbba6d2d_0
- cuda-nvdisasm=11.8.86=0
- cuda-nvml-dev=11.6.55=haa9ef22_0
- cuda-nvprof=11.8.87=0
- cuda-nvprune=11.6.124=he22ec0a_0
- cuda-nvrtc=11.6.124=h020bade_0
- cuda-nvrtc-dev=11.6.124=h249d397_0
- cuda-nvtx=11.6.124=h0630a44_0
- cuda-nvvp=11.8.87=0
- cuda-runtime=11.6.2=0
- cuda-samples=11.6.101=h8efea70_0
- cuda-sanitizer-api=11.8.86=0
- cuda-toolkit=11.6.2=0
- cuda-tools=11.6.2=0
- cuda-visual-tools=11.6.2=0
- ffmpeg=4.3=hf484d3e_0
- freetype=2.12.1=h4a9f257_0
- gds-tools=1.4.0.31=0
- giflib=5.2.1=h7b6447c_0
- gmp=6.2.1=h295c915_3
- gnutls=3.6.15=he1e5248_0
- idna=3.4=py39h06a4308_0
- intel-openmp=2021.4.0=h06a4308_3561
- jpeg=9e=h7f8727e_0
- lame=3.100=h7b6447c_0
- lcms2=2.12=h3be6417_0
- ld_impl_linux-64=2.38=h1181459_1
- lerc=3.0=h295c915_0
- libcublas=11.11.3.6=0
- libcublas-dev=11.11.3.6=0
- libcufft=10.9.0.58=0
- libcufft-dev=10.9.0.58=0
- libcufile=1.4.0.31=0
- libcufile-dev=1.4.0.31=0
- libcusolver=11.4.1.48=0
- libcusolver-dev=11.4.1.48=0
- libcusparse=11.7.5.86=0
- libcusparse-dev=11.7.5.86=0
- libdeflate=1.8=h7f8727e_5
- libffi=3.4.2=h6a678d5_6
- libgcc-ng=11.2.0=h1234567_1
- libgomp=11.2.0=h1234567_1
- libiconv=1.16=h7f8727e_2
- libidn2=2.3.2=h7f8727e_0
- libnpp=11.8.0.86=0
- libnpp-dev=11.8.0.86=0
- libnvjpeg=11.9.0.86=0
- libnvjpeg-dev=11.9.0.86=0
- libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
- libstdcxx-ng=11.2.0=h1234567_1
- libtasn1=4.16.0=h27cfd23_0
- libtiff=4.4.0=hecacb30_2
- libunistring=0.9.10=h27cfd23_0
- libwebp=1.2.4=h11a3e52_0
- libwebp-base=1.2.4=h5eee18b_0
- lz4-c=1.9.3=h295c915_1
- mkl=2021.4.0=h06a4308_640
- mkl-service=2.4.0=py39h7f8727e_0
- mkl_fft=1.3.1=py39hd3c417c_0
- mkl_random=1.2.2=py39h51133e4_0
- ncurses=6.3=h5eee18b_3
- nettle=3.7.3=hbbd107a_1
- nsight-compute=2022.3.0.22=0
- openh264=2.1.1=h4ff587b_0
- openssl=1.1.1s=h7f8727e_0
- pytorch-cuda=11.6=h867d48c_0
- pytorch-mutex=1.0=cuda
- readline=8.2=h5eee18b_0
- typing_extensions=4.3.0
- tzdata=2022f=h04d1e81_0
  I tried to install individual packages separately but I am unable to get a perfect source for installing them. Requesting help in finding a way to run this file

I tried running the environment file using conda but it was unsuccessfull. the pip dependencies are uploaded but the conda dependencies are not uploaded. I have channels such as

- pytorch3d-nightly

  - pytorch
  - iopath
  - fvcore
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
    in my environment.